# Let $A \in M_{3 \times 3},$ such that $A^{6}= I$, then minimal polynomial of $A$ can be of degree $3$. (True/false)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Let $A \in M_{3 \times 3},$ such that $A^{6}= I$, then minimal polynomial of $A$ can be of degree $3$.

(True/false)

Since $A^{6} = I $

$(A^{3}-1)(A^{3}+1)= 0$

I couldn't find any Jordan form having real entries for $A$, such that its minimal polynomial is of degree $3$.

Any hint$?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a matrix whose minimal polynomial is $x^3 - 1$, it suffices to use the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) to that polynomial.  In particular, 
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}
$$
has the minimal polynomial $p(x) = x^3 - 1$.

Comment: I think I can also use the concept of permutation matrix for this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What if $A$ is the matrix of a rotation of $\frac\pi3$ radians around an axis? Such as:$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-\frac12&-\frac{\sqrt3}2\\0&\frac{\sqrt3}2&-\frac12\end{bmatrix}.$$